# How do I get a Vuetify Select field with the "multiple" prop to interact with axios data from database?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a project that I am building for a school district while learning Vue. I have axios set up and working with several other fields to get and edit data from a mysql database, but I am stuck at using the multiple prop on a v-select component. I have realized that it has to do with the data type. In the database, the schools are a String, but v-select multiple requires an Array.

I am using a Vuetify data table with a dialog that opens to edit the User's Information. One of the options is a school field that should be able to assign multiple schools to a user. Here is that field:

```
<v-select
  :items='schools'
  v-model='schoolArray'
  label='School'
  multiple
  item-text='school'
></v-select>
```

Normally, v-model would have 'editedItem.school', but that returns a string and I need an array. I have a computed property to change the school data to an array:

```
schoolArray (item) {
  return this.editedItem.school.split(',')
}
```

This now lets me see what schools are in the database instead of an empty field, but this gave me an error

> "[Vue warn]: Computed property "schoolArray" was assigned to but it
> has no setter."

So, I changed it to this:

```
schoolArray: {
  get: function () {
    var stringToArray = this.editedItem.school.slice(0).split(',')
    return stringToArray
  },
  set: function (school) {
    this.editedItem.school = school
  }
}
```

Now, the error I am getting is

> '[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError:
> this.editedItem.school.slice(...).split is not a function"'

I feel like I am missing something fundamental, but I am still trying to learn Vue and Vuetify. Any help or direction would be appreciated.

Comment: how are you defining the `editedItem`?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim editedItem is defined like this: editedItem: { firstname: '', lastName: '', school: '', email: '', phone: '', view: '', role: '' },

Comment: Looking at it again, that would mean that the database is a string, editedItem is an object and v-select multiple requires an array. Am I seeing that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting the `editedItem.school` to an **array**, instead of **string**, so it complains that you can't `split()` an array.

When you set the `editedItem.school`, you should transform it back to string via `Array.join(",")`.

```js
export default {
  data: () => ({
    schools: ["Schools 1", "Schools 2", "Schools 3"],
    editedItem: {...} 
  }),

  computed: {
    schoolArray: {
      get: function() {
        return this.editedItem.school.slice(0).split(",");
      },
      set: function(school) {
        // set it back to a string using `join(",")`
        this.editedItem.school = school.join(","); 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Here's a sample demo on codesandbox.](https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-frost-qbpt4?file=/src/components/Playground.vue:622-664)

Comment: Thanks. That did the trick! Do you know why it leaves a comma at the front of the string (in my code, but not yours) if I uncheck everything and check a new value?

Comment: I figured it out. It was outputing "" when nothing was selected, so it wasn't truly empty. I fixed it by changing the get function to: get: function () {
        return this.editedItem.school === '' ? null : this.editedItem.school.slice(0).split(', ')
      },

Comment: Oh, that's great. Or you can set it to `[]` instead of `null` so `this.editedItem.school` is always an array. :)